# (react) ref.current.clientWidth in useEffect is getting the wrong value during the initial mount

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I am having a trouble setting the `ref.current.clientWidth` during the initial render in the `useEffect`. In the `useEffect` hook, it will first obtain the `ref.current.clientWidth`, and then store that value by a `setState` hook.

The code is like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const windowWidthChange = ref.current.clientWidth;
        setCurrentWidthChange(windowWidthChange);
    }, []);
```

But it is weird that the value stored in the `currentWidthChange` is deviated from the correct value when I manually `console.log` the current clientWidth out:

[image]

Has anyone got an idea what is causing this? Much appreciated.

Edit:
This doesn't happen every time I load the page, only 20% of the time will it get the wrong value.

Comment: Looks like a scrollbar appears

Comment: But it doesn't happen every time I reloaded, the chances are like 20% when it gets a wrong value.

Comment: Try using `debugger`